# Stream identified Song through Gracenote GNSDK Android

Tags: android, stream, gracenote

I have done a simple tutorial to identify a raw song, it detects the song through gracenote GNSDK and returns the GDO,

But I want to play(i.e. stream) that detected song through the gnsdk, IS IT POSSIBLE???

Comment: Sorry, I know this isn't the right place to ask, but what tutorial did you use? I'm curious to follow it as well. Thanks.

Comment: @jamesmstone follow these links for guidance https://github.com/richadams/java-gracenote            https://developer.gracenote.com/web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracenote does not provide audio streams, just metadata and recommendations. You need to use APIs from streaming music services like [Deezer](http://developers.deezer.com), [Spotify](http://developer.spotify.com), [Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/developers), and others to play the actual songs. If you configure GNSDK to return XID's with the GDO, you can get Deezer ID's that link directly to the Deezer API.

Comment: I am not getting the XIDs, but I can get the XID's with the GDO, but how to use it with as you say DEEZER api?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am thinking to stream the detected song with the SoundCloud api, can Gracenote returns XID for SoundCloud?

Comment: We do not return XIDs for SoundCloud. But you can use the artist and track title returned from Gracenote to do a text search with the SoundCloud API , as documented at https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search